# Unable to change nav-pills default background color from blue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I can't for the life of me get rid of nav-pills' default blue background color. Before you ask, I have looked up similar questions, tried the proposed solutions, modified some but nothing seems to work. I'm fairly new to HTML/CSS and this is probably going to be some silly question, but what the hell. [Since I'm working with a grey background navigation bar, I'd like the tabs to have a color that'd complement it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vos93.png).

Here's the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Random.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
      <li><a href="#" target="_blank">C.O. Dev.</a>
      </li>
      <li class="pull-right"><a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li class="pull-right"><a href="#">My Work</a>
      </li>
      <li class="pull-right"><a href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="pull-right active"><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I assume `Random.css` is your own CSS? If so, make sure to load it *after* Bootstrap so you have a chance to overwrite definitions. CSS works defined last wins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must override it with your custom css. `nav.less` ruled the style of active nav. create your own css and use this:

```
.nav-pills>li.active>a{
 color: #337ab7 !important;
 background-color: #eee !important;
}
```

```css
.nav-pills>li.active>a{
 color: #337ab7 !important;
 background-color: #eee !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Random.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
      <li><a href="#" target="_blank">C.O. Dev.</a>
      </li>
      <li class="pull-right"><a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li class="pull-right"><a href="#">My Work</a>
      </li>
      <li class="pull-right"><a href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="pull-right active"><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. Adding the '!important' part did the trick. I was omitting it.

Comment: [When to use !important](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/)

Comment: if my answer suits your needs, accepting the aswer as correct would be very much appreciated. :D

Comment: Most definitely. Almost forgot that.